# Definition of 3NF

Tags: database-normalization

I'm rather confused about the definition of 3NF.
Let R be a relation with attribute set X.
Suppose Y -> A is a functional dependency where A is a non-prime attribute and Y is a subset of X.

If Y is a proper subset of any candidate key for R, then the relation is not in 3NF (and not even in 2NF) because this is a partial dependency, which is not permitted in 2NF (and by extension 3NF).

If Y is a non-prime attribute, the relation is not in 3NF because this is a transitive dependency of the non-prime attribute A on any candidate key through the non-prime attribute Y.

But what if Y  is a set containing both prime and non-prime attributes? What if A is a subset of Y? What if Y contains only prime attributes, but those prime attributes come from different keys of R so that Y is not a proper subset of any particular key of R? What if Y contains only, but multiple non-prime attributes? Which of these cases violates the requirements of 3NF and why?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR **Get definitions straight.**

---

**To know whether a case violates 3NF you have to look at the criteria used in some definition.**

Your question is rather like asking, I know an even number is one that is divisible by 2 or one whose decimal representation ends in 0, 2, 4, 6 or 8, but what if it's three times a square? Well, you have to *use the definition*--show that the given conditions imply that it's divisible by two or that its decimal representation ends in one of those digits. Why do you even care about other properties than the ones in the definition?

When some FDs (functional dependencies) hold, others must also hold. We say the latter are implied by the former. So when given FDs hold usually tons of others also hold. So one or more arbitrary FDs holding doesn't necessarily tell you anything about any normal forms might hold. Eg when U is a superset of V, U → V must hold; such FDs are called *trivial* because they are implied by any collection of FDs. Eg when U → V, every superset of U determines every subset of V. *Armstrong's axioms* are some rules that can be mechanically applied to find all FDs that hold. There are algorithms to find a *canonical/minimal/irreducible cover* for a given set, a set of FDs that imply all those in it with no proper subset that does. There are also algorithms to determine whether a relation satisfies certain NFs (normal forms), and to decompose them into components with higher NFs when they're not.

**Sometimes we think there is a case that the definition doesn't handle but really we have got the definition wrong.**

The definition you are trying to refer to for a relation being in 3NF actually requires that there be no transitive functional dependence of a non-prime attribute on a candidate key.

In your non-3NF example you should say *there is* a transitive FD, not "this is a transitive FD", because the violating FD is of the form *CK* → A not Y → A. Also, U → V is transitive when there is an X where U → X AND X → V AND NOT X → U. It doesn't matter whether X is a prime attribute.

**PS** It's not very helpful to ask "why" something is or isn't so in mathematics. We describe a situation in terms of some givens, and a bunch of things follow. We can say that if certain of the givens weren't so then that thing wouldn't be so. But if certain *other givens* weren't so then it might also not be so. We can give a proof that something is or isn't so as "why" but it's not the only proof.